# TDS Sync with Sitecore Error: ParentItemNotFoundException

Tags: sitecore, tds

When I do a "Sync with Sitecore" for the new items present in my TDS project I get the error `ParentItemNotFoundException`. Although the parent items are already present I tried removing the parent item from Sitecore and then syncing the parent item. Parent item gets synced but even then the child items are not getting synced.

[image]

Comment: did you get solution to this? Please share if yes, it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if you have enabled the delta deploy feature in TDS. The issue arises when you add an item to your TDS project whose parent or one of it's ancestors have an updated date that is before the configured delta deploy date (`IncludeItemsChangedAfter` property). The deployment will fail because it wants to deploy the item you have added but can't because one of it's ancestors are excluded from deployment due to it's updated date.

See this post for more information about the delta deploy feature http://www.seanholmesby.com/true-delta-deploys-with-tds-classic/